# How can i upgrade ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

Currently i am working with ubuntu 10.10, and I want to upgrade directly to ubuntu 12.04 without upgrading to intermediate versions of ubuntu...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to upgrade going through the ranks, but i not sure i not done it any other way. I near sure if you go to the update manager you will find options there to upgrade to 12.04 ubuntu without having to go next 11.04 or whatever comes next.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command for that:

do-release-upgrade

ref:
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html